# Can we change for loop result into list with index?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently learning python, I just have one little question over here.

I used for loop and getting a result below.

Here is my code:

```
def psuedo_random(multiplier, modulus, X_0, x_try):
    for i in range(x_try):
        place_holder = []
        count = []
        next_x = multiplier * X_0 % modulus
        place_holder.append(next_x)
        X_0 = next_x
        for j in place_holder:
            j = j/modulus
            count.append(j)
            print(count)
```

Result:

```
[0.22021484375]

[0.75439453125]

[0.54443359375]

[0.47705078125]
```

Can we somehow change it into something like this?

```
[0.22021484375, 0.75439453125, 0.54443359375, 0.47705078125]
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: posted it sir, sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

After you initialized a list, you can use append function in the loop.

initialize a list where you want to list these numbers
`mylist = []`

use this function in your for loop

```
for i in .....:
   mylist.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Do not initialize your list inside the loop. Just place it outside.